# How to detect when an embedded iOS AVPlayerViewController has an error retrieving a file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer

I have an iOS app written in Objective-C which has a view that embeds an AVPlayerViewController in it. In my Storyboard I have a Cointainer View in a ViewController, from the Container View I have an 'embed' segue to a AVKit Player View Controller. The code that initializes the AVPlayerViewController passes a URL to some video file that can be played. This is an example of my code in the prepareForSegue method in the parent View Controller class.

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerController = [segue destinationViewController];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somehost.com/My_Video.mp4"];
playerController.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:videoURL];
```

From this point is there anyway to detect if the AVPlayer encountered an error loading the file from the URL in the code of the containing ViewController?